# How to get positional arguments name in visual studio code 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a asp.net MVC project in Visual Studio 2019.

I am watching a tutorial and the tutor uses Visual Studio 2015. His editor shows parameter name beside parameter, like this:

[image]

While my editor doesn't:

[image]

Does any one know what setting, feature or extension is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "inline parameter name hint". Not sure how VS 2015 can have it since even Resharper only introduce it on [2018](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/11/27/inline-parameter-name-hints-c-vb-net-resharper-rider/) (maybe CodeRush or another extension?), but if you're using the latest VS, it's available under the [Editor Help group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?view=vs-2019#editor-help) from Tools-Options-Text Editor-C#-Advanced. This feature is turned on by default in all IDEA-based IDE (Rider, Android Studio, PhpStorm, etc) so expect more people to be used by it.

Comment: I turned on that Option, restarted my VS, still inline parameter hints are not shown. (PS: Tutor uses VS 2015 Enterprise)

Comment: @thisisjaymehta Your tutor edition doesn't matter, since that feature is only introduced on VS 2019 around August. I can't replicate the bug, the hint show up correctly. Try disabling other extensions (if any) and if it's still not showing up, open up a bug report

Comment: Its not that big of a problem so I will just leave it, instead of opening a bug report. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I installed ReSharper Extension and got it working. Thanks.